How to left blank/fill up a column with zeros depending on a string value of a cell?
I am manipulating an excel file with three different sheets:
Ideally, the Dummy column has to be filled up with zeros by default, except for when the student's name is either 'Roberto' or 'Leonardo', in such case, the Dummy column values shall remain in blank.

My original DF looks like this:

{'Sheet_1':     ID      Name  Surname  Grade favourite color    favourite sport  Dummy
 0  104  Eleanor     Rigby      6            blue  American football    NaN
 1  168  Barbara       Ann      8            pink             Hockey    0.0
 2  450    Polly   Cracker      7           black      Skateboarding    NaN
 3   90   Little      Josy     10          orange            Cycling    NaN,
 'Sheet_2':     ID       Name   Surname  Grade favourite color favourite sport  Dummy
 0  106       Lucy       Sky      8          yellow          Tennis    NaN
 1  128    Delilah     Perez      5     light green      Basketball    0.0
 2  100  Christina   Rodwell      3           black       Badminton    NaN
 3   40      Ziggy  Stardust      7             red          Squash    NaN,
 'Sheet_3':     ID   Name   Surname  Grade favourite color favourite sport  Dummy
 0   22   Lucy  Diamonds      9           brown            Judo    NaN
 1   50  Grace     Kelly      7           white       Taekwondo    NaN
 2  105    Uma   Thurman      7          purple      videogames    NaN
 3   29   Lola   McQueen      3             red            Surf    0.0}


And I would like to write a loop to end up with something like this:

{'Sheet_1':     ID      Name  Surname  Grade favourite color    favourite sport  Dummy
 0  104  Eleanor     Rigby      6            blue  American football    NaN
 1  168  Barbara       Ann      8            pink             Hockey    NaN
 2  450    Polly   Cracker      7           black      Skateboarding    NaN
 3   90   Little      Josy     10          orange            Cycling    NaN,
 'Sheet_2':     ID       Name   Surname  Grade favourite color favourite sport  Dummy
 0  106       Lucy       Sky      8          yellow          Tennis      0
 1  128    Delilah     Perez      5     light green      Basketball      0
 2  100  Christina   Rodwell      3           black       Badminton      0
 3   40      Ziggy  Stardust      7             red          Squash      0,
 'Sheet_3':     ID   Name   Surname  Grade favourite color favourite sport  Dummy
 0   22   Lucy  Diamonds      9           brown            Judo    NaN
 1   50  Grace     Kelly      7           white       Taekwondo    NaN
 2  105    Uma   Thurman      7          purple      videogames    NaN
 3   29   Lola   McQueen      3             red            Surf    NaN}


I haven't mentioned yet that the student's name is written on the B2 cell of every sheet (that means that all of the sheets have the same format).

Kindly appreciate any help. I am finding it hard to figure out how to make the program to consider the information written in each sheet, and hence, applying the loop with the condition of letting the column in blank if 'Roberto' or 'Leonardo' are found to be in B2. The code below simply fills up the Dummy column with zeros in all of the sheets (which is not my expected output):
# Importing modules
import openpyxl as op
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

# Defining the file path
file_path = r'C:/Users/machukovich/stack_2.xlsx'

# Load workbook as openpyxl
reference_workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
wb = load_workbook(file_path)

# We will mantain the workbook open
wb = wb.active

# Loading the file into a dictionary of Dataframes
dict_of_df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=None, skiprows=2)

# Reading up the B2 cell for later use:
student_name = wb['B2'].value

# Writting the loop itself (it fills all the 'Dummy' columns with zeros in all sheets):
for sheet_name, df in dict_of_df.items():
      df['Dummy'] = df['Dummy'].fillna(0)

EDIT: I have modified the code to be replicable, and take into consideration that the cell B2 is not appearing in none of the above DF's. That's why I am skipping the first two rows in each of the excel sheets. Leonardo and Roberto are appearing in B2 of Sheet_1 and Sheet_3 respectively.




Your input doesn't seem to be a dataframe but rather a dictionary of dataframes. Can you provide a reproducible input? Maybe {k: d.to_dict('tight') for k,d in dfs_excel_file.items()}

Your desired output doesn't match the constraint that only students with the name "Leonardo" or "Roberto" have blank values. Under that constraint, all the values in your output should be 0 as none of the students have those names.

I have modified the code and added some more explanations about B2

@machukovich thanks but this is not really reproducible. We would need to spend significant time the create a file that matches your description. Can't you provide a piece of code that generates such an example file. Ideally we should just have to copy/paste your code.

Thanks for your answer @mozway, please review my edit and if it is still not clear enough I can try to post the question again. Will follow your advise.

Try this:
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl

# Defining the file path
file_path = r'C:/Users/machukovich/stack_2.xlsx'

# Load workbook as openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)

# Loading the file into a dictionary of DataFrames
dict_of_df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=None, skiprows=2)

# Writting the loop itself
for sheet_name, df in dict_of_df.items():
    # Read the student's name from cell B2 of the current sheet
    student_name = wb[sheet_name]['B2'].value
    # If the student's name is 'Roberto' or 'Leonardo', keep 'Dummy' column NaN, else fill with 0
    df['Dummy'] = df['Dummy'].apply(lambda x: x if student_name in ['Roberto', 'Leonardo'] else 0)

# Save the modified DataFrame back to the Excel file
with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path) as writer:
    for sheet_name, df in dict_of_df.items():
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)


